# Emacs lisp button action not working properly

Tags: git, emacs, elisp

I am writing a little customization that uses git-emacs package function.
The idea was that a buffer with currently available git-repositories pops out whenever a key is pressed, allowing me to select one and automatically navigate to repo's git-status buffer.

I'm currently stuck with this code:

```
(require 'popwin)
(require 'button)
(popwin-mode 1)
(setq git-repositories (list "~/testgit/repo1/" "~/repo2/" "~/gitlab/repo3"))

(defun select-git-repository-from-list()
  (interactive)
  ;; fill buffer with data from git-repositories
  (with-output-to-temp-buffer "*git-repositories*"
    (with-current-buffer "*git-repositories*"
      (dolist (repo git-repositories)
        ;; we use 'local' variable because if insert-text-button value
        ;; is set like (car blah), call to `car` is issued when button is pressed,
        ;; so the it does return first element in the list
        (setq pos (position repo git-repositories))
        (insert-text-button repo 'action (lambda (x) (delete-window) (git-status (nth pos git-repositories))))
        (newline)
        )
      (push '("*git-repositories*" :height 10) popwin:special-display-config)))
  )
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c \\") 'select-git-repository-from-list)
```

which does not work as expected: 
This creates a minibuffer, fills it with text buttons, that are to trigger `(git-status dir)`. The problem is that git-status is successfully called when i push the first button. The other two give me error `if: fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`. I guess the path is null or corrupted, that is why .git is not found.

So, the question is:
How should this code be rewritten?

Regards,
Mike.

Comment: A possible candidate for: [emacs.stackexchange](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Can't you change `(nth pos git-repositories)` to just `repo` , and remove `(setq pos ... )`?

Answer (score 1):

Your long comment inside your function gives the clue of the problem: the moment when code and variables are evaluated is not what you seem to expect. You may solve your problem doing something like this:

```
(defun select-git-repository-from-list()
  (interactive)
  ;; fill buffer with data from git-repositories
  (with-output-to-temp-buffer "*git-repositories*"
    (with-current-buffer "*git-repositories*"
      (dolist (repo git-repositories)
        (insert-text-button repo 'action `(lambda (x) (delete-window) (git-status ,repo)))
        (newline))
      (push '("*git-repositories*" :height 10) popwin:special-display-config))))
```

Notice the backquote: I am quoting a list (code, if fact, as it is a lambda), but I am selectively evaluating a variable inside it (that is what the comma is used for).